# How to Install .ipa file from PC with iTunes 12.6.2.20

Tags: ios, iphone, itunes, ipa

I tried with following steps:-

(1) Drag-and-drop IPA file into 'Apps' tab of iTunes BEFORE you connect the iPhone device. iTunes is installed on Windows 7 Professional machine.

(2) Connect your iPhone device using USB cable to machine.

(3) Select your device on iTunes

(4) Select 'Apps' tab

(5) Search app that you want to install

(6) Click on 'Install' button. This will change to 'Will Install'

(7) Click on 'Apply' button on right corner. This will initiate process of app installation. You can see status on top of iTunes as well as app on device.

(8) The “App installation” will start on your device with progress….

Now app installation stops in iPhone and progress sign disappears in iPhone. The status of app changes to 'Remove' at iTunes

It would be great if someone helps on this. We have tried above steps with iPad as well but still not working.

Comment: Which app you are trying to install ? From where did you get the app ? Whether you downloaded it using iTunes or Synced to your PC previously ?

Comment: @Midhun, this app is created by development for testing purpose. We are using iTunes to install & Sync the app on iPhone.

Comment: In that case check whether you are signing the app using correct certificate and you have included the device id in the development provisioning profile.

Comment: @Midhun, that would not be a concern I believe because the same app was installed by others at different location.